# FQL Query returns less results than the limit I set

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-php-sdk

So I created an FQL query in the Graph Api offered by fb developers website and knowing that without a limit it returns the last 100 results i used "Limit 10000".

While i was reading the results i realized that it didn't even bring all the results then.

When I use the same query in a php file in my website it returns only 1086 results.

Anyone know why is that happening?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possibly only that many results exist? What were you querying?

Comment: i was looking to find all the messages i recieved:

SELECT body,created_time,message_id,thread_id 
FROM message 
WHERE thread_id IN (SELECT thread_id 
FROM thread 
WHERE folder_id = 0)
LIMIT 10000

Comment: Are you sure you have more than 10,000 messages that you have received? Average 20 received messages per conversation (NOTE: Average, and only Received messages) - are you sure you have 500 conversations?

Comment: maybe putting it in numbers the results do make sense. I will look more into it. Thank you a lot!